# Problems with Session losing its data in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have allready asked this question before, but now I have found more details and some more weird stuf.

I have a web project that has 2 .aspx files that connect data with sessions. Without any extra code this works, when i add my extra code the session no longer works. Does anybody have an idea why?

Code where sessions work:

Form1:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["data"] = "5";
}
protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (string)(Session["data"]); // 5 when i look while debugging
    Response.Redirect("~/Form2.aspx", false);
}
```

Form 2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (string)(Session["data"]); // s = 5 when i look while debugging
}
protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (string)(Session["data"]); // s = 5 when i look while debugging
}
```

Code where sessions don't work: (i use 2 classlibraries (logic and dataAccess where I get data from json webservice and parse it to my forms).
Form1:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Logic logic = new Logic();
    logic.login(credentials);
    List<AppointmentExtParticipant> opleidingVolgers = logic.getOpleidingVolgers();
    foreach (AppointmentExtParticipant app in opleidingVolgers)
    {
        if (app.contact != null)
        {
            Relation rel = logic.getRelationData(app.contact.FK_RELATION);
            DropDownListUsers.Items.Add(app.ToString() + " " + rel.ToString());
        }
    }
    Session["data"] = "5";
}

protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (string)(Session["opleidingvolger"]); // s = 5 when i look while debugging
    Response.Redirect("~/Form2.aspx", false);
}
```

Form 2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (string)(Session["data"]); // s = null when i look while debugging
}
protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (string)(Session["data"]); // s = null when i look while debugging
}
```

Ofcourse I simplified the names here a bit so people could understand, thnx!

edit:

logic login:
[image]
dataaccess login:
[image]

Here i get data from my webservice hosted on another url.

Comment: @usman sorry to bother you!

Comment: @mason Sorry to bother you, this is the problem I am now facing.

Comment: something in those classes are clearing the session so can you show whats happening in logic.login ?

Comment: @Usman ofc, gona eddit the tekst

Comment: @Usman I was lazy so i put images. The weird thing is that i still don't get the Session even if i declare it after my logic methods.

Comment: it should work when you declare after logic

Answer (score 1):

Sessions generally work by using cookies.You are using `HttpWebRequests` which creates new `session`So you need to preserve session cookie between requests. Thats why we use `CookieContainer`  so add

```
 CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(
             "")  as HttpWebRequest;
 req.CookieContainer = container;
```

Comment: Thnx for the time, I will try it tomorrow.